# MySQL C++ , function return row as string

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm writing telegram bot and I need to get data from DB and send it as text data. I have simple table.

```
CREATE TABLE Topics (
    ID CHAR(5),
    `GENERAL QUESTION` TEXT(120) NOT NULL,
    `COMPILATION` TEXT(220) NOT NULL,
    `C++ and OOP` TEXT(220) NOT NULL,
    `STL ALGORITHM` TEXT(120) NOT NULL,
    `OS LINUX` TEXT(120) NOT NULL
);
```

A piece of code.

```
 bot.getEvents().onCallbackQuery([this,&bot](const CallbackQuery::Ptr& query) {
    if (query->data == "Junior") {
       bot.getApi().sendMessage(query->message->chat->id, to_string(get_topics('j')));

    }

char MainBot::get_topics(char lvl) {


    if(lvl == 'j') {
        res = mysql_perform_query(con, "select * from Topics;");

        while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {
            // the below row[] parametes may change depending on the size of the table and your objective
             std::cout << row[0] << " | " << row[1] << " | " << row[2] << " | " << row[3] << " | " << row[4] << std::endl;

            return *gettext(row[1]); // or just return *row[1]
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that it returns a number value not string data. Maybe there is a way to do it correctly.

Comment: You cannot return string data from a function declared `char`. If you want to return string data use `std::string`.

Comment: What exactly "Returns a number" ?

Comment: @SimplyCode I fill my row with thtis text data "В чем заключаются основные принципы ООП?" and i have this number 32

Comment: @john YESSS Yore right. Before I have tried with CSTRING to std:: string

Comment: `char` is an integer datatype, so of course you're getting a number. `32` is the ASCII code for the space character.